# Сhange menu after scrolling the first screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

How to change the menu background after scrolling the first screen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > window.innerHeigh)
    menu.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";;
  else
    menu.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Яцьків Юрий,
does this help?

```
window.onscroll=function(ev)
{
 if((window.innerHeight+window.scrollY)>=document.body.offsetHeight)
 {
  document.getElementById('myawesomebackground').style.backgroundImage='myawesomeimage.png';
 }
};
```